# SWT Browser control not loading Plugin

Tags: java, internet-explorer, swt, activex

I am embedding the browser widget in SWT application. Browser(IE) is able to redirect to the required website but it is not able to use the active x plugin.
If I open the URL using the standalone Internet Explorer it is able to access the plugin and web site works properly.
Have checked that plugin is enabled for all websites in IE Add-ons window.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you set `browser.setJavascriptEnabled(true)` ?